# Перестал подсвечиваться синтаксис в VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Частично перестал окрашиваться синтаксис в vs code. Пытался переустановить, удалять файлы в из AppData/Roaming , менял тему, просто в один момент const, let, строки стали как обычный текст.

Пара скриншотов как эта проблема выглядит (реакт на ts, в обычном js тоже самое):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой файл настроек

```
    {
      "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.tabSize": 2,
      "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
      "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
      "git.confirmSync": false,
      "git.autofetch": true,
      "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
      "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
      "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales": {
        "ru": true
      },
      "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
      "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
      "prettier.singleQuote": true,
      "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
      "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
      "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
      "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open"
    }
```

Comment: А какой язык определяет для файла?

Comment: как нужно, где ts определяет ts, где просто js определяет js

Comment: Пробовали ставить `Typescript React`/`Javascript React`?

Comment: Если вы используете Инсайдерскую сборку, то кажись вышли кривые пару обновлений. Если это и в стабильной сборке - странно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson ну он их так и определяет, сборка стабильная. Самое странное что переустановка не помогает, может я не все файлы с настройками vs code удалил, у него же только в пути установки есть файлы и в AppData/Roaming или где-то ещё?

Comment: Еще есть тут `AppData\Local\Programs`, но у меня кажись такая же проблема, только у меня инсайдерская сборка. Странно.

Comment: нашул ещё тут `%APPDATA%\Code` и тут `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`, удалил их и все вышеречисленные пути, переустановил code  и всё заработало

Answer (score 1):

Путём удаления сотни файлов понял что проблема в расширении, а именно [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) от Microsoft, удалил его и всё работает как нужно...

*(на момент написания ответа, вышло обновление, решающее эту проблему)*